# Determinant properties from eigenvalue definition without the Laplace expansion

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, field-theory, determinant

The determinant of an $n \times n$ matrix $A$ over $\mathbb{C}$ or $\mathbb{R}$ is usually defined in one of three ways: as the ratio of the measure of a set to the measure of its image under $A$, as a map from matrices to real or complex numbers satisfying a list of properties (preserving multiplication, changing sign with row and column permutations, being zero when a matrix is non-invertible), or through the recursive algorithm known as the Laplace expansion. The first definition is geometric and hard to extend to an arbitrary field, the second relies on the third to prove such a map exists, and the third relies on the second to justify why we would care about the result of such a seemingly arbitrary algorithm.

Sheldon Axler's "Down with Determinants" provides a different approach, defining the determinant instead as the product of the complex eigenvalues of a matrix counted with multiplicity. This can easily be generalized from $\mathbb{C}$ to an arbitrary algebraically closed field $K$, since the argument given by Axler for the existence of $n$ eigenvalues counting multiplicity relies only on the fact that $\mathbb{C}$ is algebraically closed.

However, later parts of the paper rely on the fact that a finite-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{C}$ is an inner product space for some inner product, which doesn't work for fields other than $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$, meaning the arguments don't generalize to arbitrary algebraically closed fields.

So what I'm wondering is, is there a nice argument that the product of the determinants of two matrices is the determinant of the product based on Axler's definition of the determinant, which avoids invoking the Laplace expansion and which works for an arbitrary algebraically closed field?

EDIT: confused Cramer's rule with the Laplace expansion.

Comment: Cramer's Rule is *not* a definition of determinants, but a rather nice theorem to solve square linear systems of equations by means of determinants...under one very special condition (the coefficients matrix must be regular)

Comment: I think you mean [Laplace expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_expansion) for the recursive definition. Cramer's rule is a method for solving a system of linear equations, or equivalently, for inverting a matrix.

Comment: Methods 2 and 3 taken together have the advantage of working for arbitrary commutative rings.